# What lattices yield integer Weierstrass invariants g2 and g3/Eisenstein series G4, G6?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

The basic question is rather short: for a lattice $\Lambda_\tau = \mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z$, one can define the Eisenstein series $G_k(\tau) = \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\tau \setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{\lambda^k}$.

> **Question:** can someone give a list of say five $\tau \in \mathbb H :=$ the upper half plane $\{z\in \mathbb C: \Im(z)>0\}$ s.t. $G_4(\tau)$ and $G_6(\tau)$ are both integers?

---

Background: for $\tau \in \mathbb H$ (the upper half plane $\{z\in \mathbb C: \Im(z)>0\}$), one can cook up a lattice $\Lambda_\tau := \mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z$, from which one can cook up the (Riemann surface) complex torus $\mathbb T_\tau := \mathbb C/\Lambda_\tau$, on which one can define the [Weierstrass function and its derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#Laurent_expansion) ($g_2:= 60G_4, g_3:=140G_6$):
$$\wp_\tau(z) := \frac 1{z^2} + \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\tau \setminus \{0\}} \left(\frac{1}{(z-\lambda)^2} - \frac 1{\lambda^2}\right), \quad \wp_\tau'(z) = 4 \wp_\tau(z)^3 - g_2(\tau) \wp_\tau(z) -g_3(\tau),$$

using which we can define the [biholomorphic group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) $\big[z \mapsto [1:\wp(z):\frac 12\wp'(z)] \big]$ from $\mathbb T_\tau$ to its image in $\mathbb C \mathbb P^2$ (the complex projective plane).

My question boils down to finding some explicit examples of lattices (parameterized by $\tau$) so that the Weierstrass elliptic curve for that lattice has integer coefficients.

---

For "natural choices" of $\tau \in \mathbb H$, one can do some crazy integral/sum manipulations to get the values of $g_2$ and $g_3$, but they don't seem to be integers in those cases: [Invariant $g_2$ in Weierstrass's elliptic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197710/invariant-g-2-in-weierstrasss-elliptic-function), [What are values of Eisenstein Series G2 on some specific points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140900/what-are-values-of-eisenstein-series-g2-on-some-specific-points), https://mathoverflow.net/questions/340154/determination-of-special-values-of-eisenstein-series. The [Wikipedia page also has a picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#/media/File:Weierstrass_elliptic_function_P.png) of the Weierstrass $\wp_\tau$ function with $g_2 = 1+i$ and $g_3=2-3i$, though unfortunately it doesn't explain the process behind making this picture.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand your horizons a little bit about what integer lattices we can look at then this is pretty straightforward. We might find the $G_k$ originally by studying the Taylor series of $\wp$ (this is done in most introductory books on the topic), so recall that in this context $G_k (\tau )$ is defined by the series $\displaystyle{ \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda'} \lambda^{-k} } $. Some observation and then computation will show us that the $G_k$ value for the lattice $\Lambda$ spanned by $<1,\tau> $ differs from the $G_k$ value for the lattice $c \Lambda $ spanned by $ <c, c\tau> $ by a constant multiple:

$\displaystyle{ \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda'} (c \cdot \lambda)^{-k} = c^{-k} \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda'} \lambda^{-k}}  $.

Note that here $c$ can be any complex number.

As you cite it's known that for the lattice $<1, i>$ that $\displaystyle{ g_2(i) = \frac{\Gamma(1/4)^8}{16 \pi^4}}$. Can you see how the above observation about the $G_k$ value for a scalar multiple of a lattice allows us to get to what you want from this result? What $c$ should I select to get from the previously found $g_2(i)$ to a lattice where the $g_2$ value is 3?

Comment: Ok, nice idea (though I really would prefer to work with "standard form" lattices since they are, well, standard). But I don't think this trick is enough to find one $\tau$ so that **both** $g_2(\tau),g_3(\tau)$ are integers.

Comment: It is, because 0 is an integer. But if you want both to be non-zero integers, then it's still ok. Try the same approach starting with $\tau = 2i $, where the values of $g_2 $ and $g_3 $ are also known (and can be found at this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Definition ). Is there a $c$ so that $g_2(2i) = \text{(integer)} \cdot c^4$ and $g_3(2i) = \text{(some other integer)} \cdot c^6$ ?

Comment: oh wow, so I guess in general the one degree of freedom $c$ is not enough to get both to be integers, but in this special case $\tau = 2i$, it works out perfectly (I guess in general if the ratio $g_2^3/g_3^2$ is some rational number you can find such a $c$ that works, so I guess related to values at which $j$ is rational). Perhaps more examples can be found with e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305239/prove-je-is-an-integer-for-an-elliptic-curve-with-cm-by-a-quadratic-field-of-c.

Comment: Also, can we say that the elliptic curve $E_{2i} = \mathbb C/\langle 1,2i\rangle$ is defined over $\mathbb Z$ since it is isomorphic-over-$\mathbb C$ to an elliptic curve with integer coefficients? I guess it's difficult to talk about the "rational points" of an elliptic-curve-$E$-over-$\mathbb C$; is the definition perhaps the rational points of a representative of the $\mathbb C$-isomorphism class of $E$ with rational coefficients?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm grasping what your idea is here. Elliptic curves are defined over fields, right?

Comment: My goal (however misguided or useless) is to visualize say rational points or integer points of some elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ or whatever in the complex torus picture. So given some equation $y^2=4x^3+Ax+B$ with integers $A,B$ say, there's a unique complex torus isomorphic to it via the Weierstrass functions (and maybe scaling like you brought up), so now we can see the rational/integer solutions to the equation in the complex torus (and then maybe we say those "are the rational/integer points of the complex torus"). Is this logically sound at least, if not useful/insightful?

Comment: The isomorphism we find is the one $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \to E $ with $ z \to ( \wp(z), \wp'(z) ) $. So we're looking for some kind of study-able consistency between the points in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ with rational image in the map. I'm not sure if there is anything like that. 
On the other hand, I found a talk https://math.mit.edu/~swshin/Fall12-18725/PadmaTalk(RationalPoints).pdf where rational points are defined in a more abstract way that doesn't directly refer to the Weierstrass form, so maybe that might help. I can't say more about it though because I don't understand the terminology!